# Running virtualbox WITHIN virtualbox: VT-x/AMD-v hardware acceleration not available?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, hardware-acceleration

My host is Windows 10, I have virtualbox installed and am running Ubuntu 14.04 as a vm and then trying to use vagrant (which requires virtualbox) inside the vm. So effectively I am running virtualbox inside virtualbox.

When I run vagrant up, I get this error:

```
VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Your 64-bit guest will fail to detect a 64-bit CPU and will not be able to boot.
```

And when I go to my vm virtualbox settings, the acceleration tab is disabled.

Is it because the host virtualbox is already making use of hardware acceleration already and therefore it is unavailable to the vm?

Is there anyway to enable it for use inside the vm?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot run a box in a box. By default, virtualization in the box is disabled for hardware reasons. That's as far as I got when attempting to do the same thing a while back.

Comment: I'm not giving your idea a death sentence, so please keep trying. I'm saying, by default it's disabled, but I'm sure you can do it with the proper knowledge and coding skill. Good luck, though!

Comment: I'd recommend installing cygwin on your windows machine and then using it to manage your vagrant installations into VirtualBox running with your Windows 10 installation. That's how I ended up doing it on a couple of systems where I was using a Windows OS as the primary OS. Pluralsight had a course; Introduction to Versioning Enivonments with Vagrant which covered it quite well if you wanted to use Virtualbox within Windows. Or a quick google will find a few articles people have written on their setups.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a fan of that idea. Would much prefer to be working in Linux. I think I might install Linux natively and just go with that.